# What seems more useful for this particular problem, Mean or Median and Why?

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving, means, median

You are given an array of positive integers. You are told to make all the numbers equal by doing this operation, i.e. to increase/decrease the value of an array element. The cost of the operation will be the amount of increment/decrement (absolute value). Find the minimum cost required to do this task.

Test Example 
Array : 2 3 1 5 2
Answer : 5

At first, it appears as though we should change all values to mean value and that should do the trick. But the optimal answer comes when using the median value. I understand that the mean is more sensitive to outliers but still, I cannot really understand why would changing values to the mean value will not give an optimal answer.

Comment: If you were confused whether it should be the median or mean, try a simple example. If the numbers were $1,1,1,1,9^{55}$. The median is 1 so only 1 number needs to be changed while if you move them to the mean they all have to be moved to the mean (and all by a fair amount).

Comment: @mathematics2x2life I understand your example. Thanks.